# How to dix error ArrayList cannot be returned by toString() in mock test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I want to test my method using mockito but I got an error `ArrayList cannot be returned by toString()`, below my code:

Method :

```
`    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<InventoryInfo> verifyStock(List<InventoryInfo> inventoryList) {
        return inventoryList.stream()
                            .map(inventory -> {
                                int availableQuantity = sumAvailableBySkuAndMerchantId(inventory.getSku(), inventory.getMerchantId());
                                inventory.setAvailable(availableQuantity >= inventory.getAvailableQuantity());
                                log.info("Available quantity for sku {} and merchant ID {} is {}", inventory.getSku(), inventory.getMerchantId(), availableQuantity);
                                return inventory;
                            })
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }`
```

the mockito test where i got the error  :

```
`
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class StandardInventoryInfraServiceTest {


    @InjectMocks
    private StandardInventoryInfraService service;

    @Mock
    private InventoryRepository repository;
    @Test
    public void testVerifyStock() {
        List<InventoryInfo> mockInventoryList = Arrays.asList(
                new InventoryInfo(1L, "product1", 2, false),
                new InventoryInfo(1L, "product2", 2, false));

        when(service.verifyStock(anyList())).thenReturn(mockInventoryList);

        verify(service, times(1)).verifyStock(mockInventoryList);
    }

}`
```

How can i fix the error please?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ArrayList cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
```

Comment: Please share some more error logs that you are getting while running the test case.

Comment: Have you override the toString method? Please check that method once.

Comment: `when(service.verifyStock(anyList())` is definitely wrong. Your service is not a mock. And if it were, what are you testing? (Correct: you are only testing mockito and _nothing_ of your production code)

Comment: can u show the service class code as well ?